# No rule to make target 'VLCQtWidgets/WidgetVideo.h', needed by 'ui_mediaplayer.h'

Tags: c++, qt, vlc, libvlc, vlc-qt

I am developing a media player using `vlc-qt`. So what I have done till now is I have clone the git repository of `vlc-qt` and have build that using `BUILDING.md` and in my '''pro''' file of `Qt` I have added the path of my `vlc-qt` installation like below

```
INCLUDEPATH+= /home/vinay/vlc-qt/build/include
LIBS+= -L/home/vinay/vlc-qt/lib -lVLCQtCore -lVLCQtWidgets
```

and I am trying to make same editor as shown by this example https://github.com/vlc-qt/examples/tree/master/simple-player

But here What It has done is that he creates one widget in UI file and then promote it to header `WidgetVideo.h` and class  `VlcWidgetVideo` So I have done the same. The path for header and class I provided in my promoted widget was

```
class name:VlcWidgetVideo
header: VLCQtWidgets/WidgetVideo.h
```

But when I build my project it shows me below error

```
No rule to make target 'VLCQtWidgets/WidgetVideo.h', needed by 'ui_mediaplayer.h'.  Stop.
```

When I include the header in the project like

```
#include "VLCQtWidgets/WidgetVideo.h
```

The file is included without showing error it means my project is able to access this file but when I run this it shows no rule error.

I don't know why it is not able to access that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include this line in your `pro` file

```
INCLUDEPATH+= /usr/local/include
```

The reason for this error is become the `ui` file is not able to access the header file because the actual system path is not included in your `pro` file and most of the time in Linux the `vlc-qt` files are installed on this location

```
/usr/local/include
```